# How remove Adobe acrobat reader DC tool bar unwanted buttons/links?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

Adobe acrobat reader DC has added whole bunch of button/links on toolbar. I would like to get rid of Home, tools, Document, Help, Mobile, and Sign In (Please see the screenshot).

Is there anyway to remove these from toolbar? It is taking too much real estate on toolbar without adding any value for me.

[image: Unwanted menus on toolbar]

Comment: Right click on the toolbar and choose "hide toolbar".  You can also use View->Show/Hide to choose what is hidden and what is visible.

Comment: [You can also edit the current toolset](https://answers.acrobatusers.com/Edit-toolbars-Acrobat-Pro-XI-q210971.aspx)

Comment: I want toolbar for all other buttons like view and navigation. You cannot edit Home.Tools,Document,?,Mobile, Sign in. Looks like they are system buttons/links.

Comment: This Acrobat Reader DC version 2015.009.20077 and not older Adobe reader.

Comment: I have provided you three possible workarounds.

Comment: I like your control tools set option but unfortunately, it odes not work with Acrobat Reader DC version 2015.009.20077 (it is the latest version, try upgrading)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32006/discussion-between-user2619299-and-ramhound).

Comment: Chat doesn't help the rest of us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of Adobe reader on 06/17/2018, have resolved this issue. Home, Tools and Signin is not part of toolbar anymore.

[image]

Comment: Unless you disable Tabs. Then they do still appear in the toolbar like the screenshot in Question shows.

Comment: @pavon, interesting... I have never disabled the tabs. but it is much without with tabs.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't found a way to remove the three Buttons "Home", "Tools" and "Document" but to shorten the displayed text in my Acrobat Reader DC 2018.009.20044, maybe this helps...

1. Find the used language file in the Locale subfolder (for me in *C:\Program 
   Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\Locale\de_DE\RdLang32.DEU*)
2. With an hex editor find these unicode strings (with quotes): "avHomeButton=xyz", "avToolsButton=xyz" and "avViewerButton=xyz"
3. Replace the text after the equal sign and finish your text with a quote
4. After your quote enter spaces overwriting the old text and the old quote until the following line break (Bytes 0D 0A)

Be sure not to break the unicode characters.

For me it looks like this:
[image: Hex dump of RdLang32.DEU after shortening some texts]

The resulting toolbar looks like this:
[image: Adobe Reader Toolbar with shorter texts]

Answer (score 1):

There is an Acrobat JavaScript method which does hide toolbar buttons, named `hideToolbarButton()`. What you will have to do, is to get the name of the buttons concerned, and then write an application-level JavaScript which you will have to install in the user's machines.

More about the use of this method, and how to find the names of the buttons can be found in the Acrobat JavaScript documentation (which is part of the Acrobat SDK Documentation, downloadable from the developer section of the Adobe website).

Comment: I doubt this will solve the issue. I just checked the AddToolBarButton.pdf example and it is creating new strip to add application buttons. The Home, Tools, Document,?, Mobile, Sign In seems to be on above. Also, can you do this scripting using just reader? I don't have license for pdf writer. Have you tested if this work?

Comment: This is "correct" behavior in Acrobat DC for addToolbarButton(). hideToolbarButton() should work. But, no, I have not tested it myself with Acrobat/Reader DC.

Comment: Now, this is the kind of user-interface design that I like!  Remove a simple capability that existed in the GUI, and make users go outside the program and write code to do it.  I can't wait for Acrobat Reader DC 2020, which will consist solely of a C-language toolkit for image display.

Answer (score 0):

Acrobat does not include that kind of toolbar customization. You can possibly get some room back by disabling Touch Mode in Preferences > General, but that won't remove any buttons. If you want a different UI, you're going to have to use different software.

Comment: I am looking for hack to do this, e.g. registry tweak, deleting plugin files, changing ini or xml settings file etc.

Comment: Acrobat Reader used to allow it.  I think I'm going to refuse to accept future Reader DC "downgrade" offers from Adobe.  Lately it gets less functional and more annoying each time.